# What's happened to Community Wiki?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-wiki

The option to mark a question as a Community Wiki appears to have disappeared. Is this deliberate or has a bug crept in to the SE engine?

Answer (score 3):

Marking new questions as community wiki was removed. Note that *answers* can still be marked community wiki, just not new questions. If you want a question marked community wiki, flag it for moderator's attention.

You can read more about the change here: [Community Wiki checkbox missing in action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action)

Comment: note that *answers* can still be marked community wiki, just not new questions.

Comment: I made the mistake of marking a question as community wiki once. I think it is a good thing that it is reserved for moderators, because some people (me) may be overly inclined to use it. The question was http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3941/what-is-impedance